# XML can't write xmlns to child nodes

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

Hi I have 3 classes like that:

```
public abstract class XmlNs
{
    public const string XmlnsAttribute = "urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents";
}


[Serializable]
public class BulkDataExchangeRequests : XmlNs
{
    [XmlAttribute("xmlns")]
    public string XmlNs = XmlnsAttribute;
    [XmlElement("Header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("AddFixedPriceItemRequest")]
    public List<AddFixedPriceItemRequest> ListAddFixedPriceItemRequest { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class AddFixedPriceItemRequest : XmlNs
{
    [XmlElement("ErrorLanguage")]
    public string ErrorLanguage { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("WarningLevel")]
    public string WarningLevel { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public ItemType Item { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute("xmlns")]
    public string XmlNs = XmlnsAttribute;
}
```

The problem is that when I serialize the object I get a correct xml but with no xmlns attribute in the AddFixedPriceItemRequest item, while in the BulkDataExchangeRequests the xmlns is correctly written....

Any help will be very appreciated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nesting elements, and nested elements are in the same namespace as their parent elements, if you don't specify anything else. So in fact your serializer is correct to *not* output the `xmlns` attribute again, as it is not needed.

See:

```
<root xmlns="my-namespace">
    <element>this is also in the namespace "my-namespace" without further declaration</element>
    <so><are><child><elements></elements></child></are></so>
</root>
```

---

EDIT:
Even though eBay is obviously not conforming to standards here, there is a solution! You can declare namespaces for the .NET xml serializer in a very convenient manner, and these declarations are kept, even if they are repeated:

```
[Serializable]
public class BulkDataExchangeRequests : XmlNs
{
    [XmlElement("Header")]
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("AddFixedPriceItemRequest")]
    public List<AddFixedPriceItemRequest> ListAddFixedPriceItemRequest { get; set; }

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName[] { new System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName("", XmlnsAttribute) });
}

[Serializable]
public class AddFixedPriceItemRequest : XmlNs
{
    [XmlElement("ErrorLanguage")]
    public string ErrorLanguage { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("WarningLevel")]
    public string WarningLevel { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Version")]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Item")]
    public ItemType Item { get; set; }

    [XmlNamespaceDeclarations]
    public XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName[] { new System.Xml.XmlQualifiedName("", XmlnsAttribute) });
}
```

The output is as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-Instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" />
  <AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" />
</BulkDataExchangeRequests>
```

Relevant documentation:

[`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlNamespaceDeclarations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Xml.Serialization.XmlNamespaceDeclarationsAttribute%29;k%28XmlNamespaceDeclarations%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)
[`System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerNamespaces.%23ctor%29;k%28XmlSerializerNamespaces%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true)

Comment: So...how can achive that? <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<BulkDataExchangeRequests xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <Version>619</Version>
  <Item>
   ...
  </Item>
</AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
<AddFixedPriceItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
  <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <Version>659</Version>
  <Item>
  ...
  </Item>
</AddFixedPriceItemRequest>
</BulkDataExchangeRequests>

Comment: This is no output by a correct serializer, and no correct parser should require the redeclaration of the namespace. That is just not needed. (This is similar to redeclaring at the beginning of _every_ sentence that the following stuff will be in English.)

Comment: I can see the same source code as you (I suppose), but I can't find any written explicit requirement for that. Have you tried sending these commands to eBay already? What is the error message (if any)?

Comment: If I don't put the namespace I get an unexpected tag error...this an ebay example https://ebay.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/6659/0/session/L2F2LzEvdGltZS8xMzc1MTg5OTY3L3NpZC9heVNRWXZ3bA==/filename/Sample+AddFixedPriceItem+request+file

Comment: If you do like my answer and it answered your question I would be delighted if you could accept it as the answer ;-)